# Agregar Archivo.css a un xml , odoo 12

Tags: css, xml, odoo

Quiero agregar un archivo.css a un template en xml , para no tener ese monton de estilos en linea que hacen el codigo ilegible.

He estado intentando varias cosas que he leido pero ninguna funciona.

Este es mi archivo css

```
.rojo{
    background-color: red;
}
.verde{
    background-color: green;
}
```

esta en la ruta mi_module/static/css/style.css

mi archivo xml tiene lo siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <openerp>    
        <data>
            <template id="111" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend">
                <xpath expr="link[last()]" position="after">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="/hn_pos_sar/static/css/style.css"/>
                </xpath>
              <t t-call="web.html_container">
                    <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                       <div class="rojo"> este div deberia de aparecer en rojo</div>
                       <div class="verde">este div deberia de aparecer en verde</div>
                    </t>
                </t>    
            </template> 
       </data>   
   </openerp>

</odoo>
```

Pero sigue sin funcionar , mis div no toman el estilo que estoy instanciando en mi archivo css, no tira error , pero se aplican los cambios.

Gracias de Antemano

Answer (score 0):

Para enlazar un archivo 'css' en un código 'xml' con 'odoo' se de seguir la siguiente estructura de código según he visto en páginas de referencia:

```
 <odoo>
     <openerp>
         <data>  
             <template id="assets_common" name="your_module_name assets" inherit_id="web.assets_common">  
                 <xpath expr="." position="inside">  
                     <link rel='stylesheet' href="/fr/your_module_name/static/src/css/your_file.css"/> 
                 </xpath>  
             </template>  
         </data>  
      </openerp>
  </odoo>
```

La diferencia que encontré con tu código es que la url cambia ya que faltaría un 'src' en ella y el 'name'. Quizá ese sea el problema. Lo he incluido en tu código:

```
 <odoo>
<openerp>    
    <data>
        <template id="111" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend">
            <xpath expr="link[last()]" position="after">
                <link rel="stylesheet" name="hn_pos_sar assets"    type="text/scss" href="/hn_pos_sar/static/src/css/style.css"/>
            </xpath>
          <t t-call="web.html_container">
                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                   <div class="rojo"> este div deberia de aparecer en rojo</div>
                   <div class="verde">este div deberia de aparecer en verde</div>
                </t>
            </t>    
        </template> 
      </data>   
   </openerp>
</odoo>
```

Aquí te dejo un enlace a una página de referencia con la documentación sobre cómo enlazar hojas de estilo en XML con ODOO que espero te pueda ser de utilidad:
https://riptutorial.com/es/odoo-8/example/11708/opcion-3---comun--agregue-archivos-css-y-javascript-para-usar-en-todas-las-paginas--backend-y-frontend-

Comment: el server da error y dice que website.assets_frontend no se encuentra en el parent

Comment: Después de revisar más documentación he realizado cambios en la respuesta a tu pregunta. Espero que te pueda resultar de ayudar. La anterior no era válida para tu problema.